# How get string from skip in DOORS DXL

Tags: string, skip, ibm-doors

I am using following code to get string from skip function. But i am getting integer numbers. I will appreciate if someone can help me out.

```
 int csvToSkip(string csv, Skip skip, char delimeter)
      {
              int i = 0
              int j = 0
              int index = 0


              for (i = 0; i < length(csv); i++)
              {
                      if (csv[i] == delimeter)
                      {
                              put(skip, 0,  "1")
                              j = i + 1
                      }
                      else if (i == length(csv) - 1)
                      {
                              put(skip, 1, "2")
                      }
              }

              return(index)
      }



      Skip mySkip=create;
      string test="hi this is test;for another test";
      char delimiter =';';
      int x=csvToSkip(test, mySkip, delimiter );
      print x;
      for sValue in mySkip do
      { 
       print (int key mySkip) " " sValue  "\n";

      }
```

This gives me following result

```
 0
      0 204534013
      1 204534015
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not declare sValue, so DXL guessed wrongly what data type the values have.

The first chapter of DXL Manual -> Language fundamentals, called "Auto-Declare", explains how you can disable the auto-declare functionality. If you do this, DOORS will warn you when you access undeclared variables.